# Scrapy - Asking too many request?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I try to get the latitude and longitude coordinate of cities from this url: https://www.latlong.net/. My code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import json

import scrapy

class geo_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "geo"
    allowed_domains = ["www.latlong.net"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.latlong.net/']

    custom_settings = {
        'COOKIES_ENABLED': True,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' : 1,
    }

    LAT_LONG_REGEX = 'sm\((?P<lat>.+),(?P<long>.+),'

    def start_requests(self):
        FILE_PATH = 'C:/Users/coppe/tutorial/cities.json'
        with open(FILE_PATH) as json_file:
            cities_data = json.load(json_file)
        for d in cities_data:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://www.latlong.net/',
                callback=self.gen_csrftoken,
                meta={'city': d['city']},
                dont_filter=True, 
            )

        def gen_csrftoken(self, response):
            city = response.meta['city']
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formid='frmPlace',
                formdata={'place': city},
                callback=self.get_geo,
                meta={'city': city}
            )

        def get_geo(self, response):
            lat_long_search = re.search(self.LAT_LONG_REGEX, response.body.decode('utf-8'))
            if lat_long_search:
                yield {
                    'coord': (lat_long_search.group('lat'), lat_long_search.group('long')),
                    'city': response.meta['city']
                }
                else:
                    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
                    inspect_response(response, self)
```

I should get something like (50,5) as coordinate for the 589 cities contained on a JSON file. Everything works except that I get (0,0) for every cities. I thought it was an issue with javascript but it's not. Indeed when I reduce my JSON file to, for example, 6 cities, I get the correct coordinate for each city. I try using the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`setting with different values (1,2 & 3) but still it does not work. Is my JSON file too heavy ? Has someone a clue about this issue ?

Comment: It can be natural. many request from one IP means bot or hacker - so they can block it (for security reason or to get acces for other users or to pay less for server). You should check HTML which you get when you get (0,0) - maybe there are some useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the website is using an API like the Google Maps geocoding API, documented at 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
That doc (not talking about doing several request at once, so not the actual API used?) says that the API link has a maximum size of 8192 characters, including the link itself and all the places you're looking for.
So yes, on top of maybe being rate limited, there must be a maximum number of characters in your city name!

A Geocoding API request takes the following form:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters
...
Note: URLs must be properly encoded to be valid and are limited to 8192 characters for all web services. Be aware of this limit when constructing your URLs. Note that different browsers, proxies, and servers may have different URL character limits as well.